# Generate fake SMS notification in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I have a smartwatch which can only pick up SMS notification (no Messenger, Whatsapp or anything). I want to use a Tasker profile to convert every Whatsapp notification I receive to a SMS notification.
I did a lot of research on internet and found this :

```
am broadcast -a android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
```

I tried it using USB debugging but it doesn't work.
Do you know how I could generate a fake received SMS notification so my watche's app can pick it up ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: No error, this is the output : `OnePlus5:/storage/emulated/0 # am broadcast -a android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED
Broadcasting: Intent { ct=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED}
Broadcast completed: result=0`
It just doesn't have any effect